# Problema al llamar función javascript desde formulario Ajax.BeginForm() en ASP.NET MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

Tengo un formulario de registro que funciona, que al ejecutarse con éxito llama a `Limpiar` que coloca en blanco el formulario,  pero si coloco el `OnBegin` deja de funcionar por completo el formulario

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Registrar", "", new AjaxOptions
            {
                HttpMethod = "POST",              
                //OnBegin = "Iniciar",
                OnSuccess = "Limpiar",  
                UpdateTargetId = "div_tabla_sucursal",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
            }
```

en un script tengo lo siguiente:

```
function Iniciar () {
    // Deshabilitamos el botón de Submit
    $("#btn_registrar").prop("disabled", true);
};

var Limpiar = function () {
    // Limpia el formulario
    $("#Frm_Registro").trigger("reset");
    // Habilitamos el botón de Submit
    $("#btn_registrar").prop("disabled", false);
    // Mostramos un mensaje de éxito.
    $("#ExitoAlert").show("slow").delay(2000).hide("slow");
};
```

la primera vez se ejecutó correctamente y si hacerle ninguna modificación dejó de ejecutarse, al quitar `onBegin` del formulario el `onSuccess` se ejecuta sin problemas, pero cuando lo coloco deja de funcionar por completo.

Comment: Si no me equivoco la línea $("#btn_registrar").prop("disabled", false) en la función Limpiar pondrá en disable  el button Si quieres habilitarlo deberías hacer un removeAttr("disabled").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dos cosas:

**Primero**: No estás indicando en el `Ajax.BeginForm` el **Controlador** al que se debe dirigir el submit del formulario

```
Ajax.BeginForm("Registrar", "aqui_el_controlador", new AjaxOptions .... )
```

**Segundo**: Estas definiendo mal la función `Iniciar()` que se llama en el `OnBegin` del la llamada AJAX.

Defínela igual que has definido la función `Limpiar` del `OnSuccess`, y te debería funcionar.

El código sería el siguiente:

```
var Iniciar = function () {
   // Deshabilitamos el botón de Submit
   $("#btn_registrar").prop("disabled", true);
};

var Limpiar = function () {
    // Limpia el formulario
    $("#Frm_Registro").trigger("reset");
    // Habilitamos el botón de Submit
    $("#btn_registrar").prop("disabled", false);
    // Mostramos un mensaje de éxito.
   $("#ExitoAlert").show("slow").delay(2000).hide("slow");
};
```

---

**PD:** Te recomiendo leas este artículo [Formularios web AJAX en ASP.NET MVC 5 - Ajax Helpers](http://www.rafaelacosta.net/Blog/2019/4/19/formularios-web-ajax-en-aspnet-mvc-5-ajax-helpers) , donde podrás ver cómo desarrollar formularios Web AJAX en ASP.NET MVC con el [Ajax Helper](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.ajaxhelper?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) **`@Ajax.BeginForm()`**.

Comment: Gracias @RafaelAcosta, estube probando llamando a function iniciar() y a var iniciar = function() y de ninguno de los casos funcionaba, hice un proyecto nuevo, copié y pegué tal cual y funciona sin problemas... y casualmente me estaba guiando de ese artículo, super útil su contenido.